# What holomorphic functions have the form $f(z) = a_1x + a_2y + a_3x^2 + a_4xy + a_5y^2 + a_6x^3 + a_7y^3$ , where $a_1, \dots , a_7 \in \mathbb C$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to determine all holomorphic functions of the form $f(z) = a_1x + a_2y + a_3x^2 + a_4xy + a_5y^2 + a_6x^3 + a_7y^3$ , where $a_1, \dots , a_7 \in \mathbb C$ .

What I've done so far is to express the (complex) coefficients ak as complex sums bk + ck × i and then write f in the form u + iv. I've also computed partial derivatives and applied the Cauchy Riemann equations to conclude that a6 = a7 = 0. So I think that we can delete the cubic terms in the expression above.

Furthermore I've observed that all second degree polynomials kz + lz^2 probably have the desired form if expressed in terms of x any y, but maybe also some other functions have this form if expressed that way, so I don't know if I've found all the functions that I wanted to find or just some of them.

Comment: Please learn [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Are $x=Re\; z$ and $y=Im\; z$?

Comment: @IrbidMath Yes.

Comment: You have found all solutions.

Comment: @geetha290krm How did you come to that conclusion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you share your derivatives and CR equations you get, I have done it on the side with CAS and unless I made errors copying the entries (which is also possible), there seems to be more affected coefficients than just $a_6$ and $a_7$.

CR1 : $(b_1-c_2)+(2b_3-c_4)x+(b_4-2c_5)y+3b_6x^2-3c_7y^2 = 0$

CR2 : $(b_2+c_1)+(b_4+2c_3)x+(2b_5+c_4)y+3c_6x^2+3b_7y^2 = 0$

Therefore after setting:

- $c_7=b_7=b_6=c_6=0\qquad a_6=a_7=0$
- $c_1=-b_2$ and $c_2=b_1\qquad a_2=ia_1$
- $c_4=2b_3$ and $b_4=-2c_3\qquad a_4=2ia_3$
- $b_5=-b_3$ and $c_5=-c_3\qquad a_5=-a_3$

I arrive to

$\begin{align}f(x,y)
&=a_1x+ia_1y+a_3x^2+2ia_3xy-a_3y^2\\
&=a_3z^2+a_1z
\end{align}$

Comment: Elegant! I got similar CR equations and similar identities for the coefficients bk and ck, but I didn't dare to proceed any further since I was afraid of getting complicated expressions that would look like a mess.

Comment: Note that you can have "guessed" the result (i.e. a polynomial in $z$ and $z^2$ and no $z^3$ as terms in $x^2y$ and $xy^2$ are missing to complete the cube). Also since $Re(z),Im(z),\bar z$ are not holomorphic you cannot have residual $x$ or $y$ alone, this is why $a_2$ is constrain to $ia_1$ and so on...

Comment: @zwim nice, and we can make the guesswork rigorous by invoking the uniqueness of analytic continuation. Define $g(z)=a_1z+a_3z^2+a_6z^3$. Then, $f$ and $g$ are entire functions which agree on the real axis, and hence must agree everywhere. So, $f(z)=a_1z+a_3z^2+a_6z^3$, so by expanding out powers of $z$, we see that the lack of an $x^2y$ or $xy^2$ term implies $a_6=0$, hence necessarily, $f(z)=a_1z+a_3z^2$. Conversely, it is clear that $f(z)=a_1z+a_3z^2$ has the desired form, with appropriate $a_2,a_4,a_5,a_6,a_7$. Hence,  polynomials $\{az+bz^2\,:\,a,b\in\Bbb{C}\}$ exhaust all possibilities.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Very nice shortcut! It would be great if we could avoid the cumbersome computations by an argument like this. I have a question though. The function g is certainly entire since it's a polynomial, but how do we know that any function f of the specified form is entire also? Do we have any reason to think that it too must be a polynomial in z?

Comment: @ $f$ is entire by assumption… atleast that’s how i read the question. You didn’t specify the set of points where $f$ is required to be holomorphic, so by default it is taken to be the entire complex plane. If you allow for weird stuff like being complex-differentiable only at the origin, then you can also have $f(x,y)= cx^2$ (or $cx^3$ for example).